# Avoiding Arrow Anti-Pattern in MISRA-C

Tags: c, coding-style, coding-standards, anti-patterns, industry-standard

For a safety-critical domain, with a code standard including the MISRA C 2004 guidelines, a "simple" piece of code becomes obtuse, chiefly because of the requirements both that all `if()` statements have an `else` and that there is only 1 return per function, and 1 break per loop. The original code looked like this:

```c
while (bIncrementalOperation(&data))
{
    vCode;
    if (bCondition1)
    {
        u16Status |= u16STATUS_N1;
        break;
    }
    if (bCondition2)
    {
        u8Var++;
    }
    if (bCondition3)
    {
        u16Status |= u16STATUS_N2;
        break;
    }
    if (bCondition4)
    {
        break;
    }
    if (bCondition5)
    {
        vCode;
    }
    else
    {
        if (bCondition6)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    vCode;
}
```

Which is long because of formatting, but fairly terse. In comparison, to attempt compliance, it becomes:

```c
bContinue = TRUE;
while (bContinue)
{
    bContinue = bIncrementalOperation(&data);
    if (!bContinue)
    {
        /* Normal exit condition: ... */
    }
    else
    {
        bContinue = bCondition1;
        if (!bContinue)
        {
            u16Status |= u16STATUS_N1;
        }
        else
        {
            u8Var += (bCondition2) ? 1U : 0U;
            bContinue = (bCondition3);
            if (!bContinue)
            {
                u16Status |= u16STATUS_N2;
            }
            else
            {
                bContinue = bCondition4;
                if (!bContinue)
                {
                    /* Normal exit condition: .... */
                }
                else
                {
                    if (bCondition5)
                    {
                        vCode;
                    }
                    else if (bCondition6)
                    {
                        /* Normal exit condition: ... */
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Continue to do IncrementalOperation */
                    }
                    vCode;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern occurs often, especially in guarding functions which test against multiple failure modes, which leads to bugs. 
Is there a better pattern, that does not break the MISRA requirements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tackle a 'branched' arrow head anti-pattern?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/205803/how-to-tackle-a-branched-arrow-head-anti-pattern)

Comment: While perhaps a duplicate question, without context, all the answers point to the optimal pattern: use multiple returns/breaks. With MISRA C, none of those answers give a valid pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Upgrade to MISRA C:2012.

MISRA C:2012  does not contain Required Rule 14.9: "An if(expression) construct must be followed by a compound statement." or Required Rule 14.10: "All if/elseif must be terminated with an 'else' clause."

Problem solved.

Rule 15.5:  "A function should have a single point of exit at the end" *is Advisory, not Required.*  The primary motivation for a single exit point is to make it easier to get manual memory management correct; if your function doesn't allocate memory, you probably don't need it.

---

Note that you're probably reading MISRA C:2004 Rule 14.10 wrong.  It only applies to `else if` statements:

> This rule applies whenever an `if` statement is followed by one or more `else if` statements; the final
>   `else if` shall be followed by an `else` statement. **In the case of a simple `if` statement then the `else`
>   statement need not be included.**
>
> The requirement for a final `else` statement is defensive programming. The `else` statement shall
>   either take appropriate action or contain a suitable comment as to why no action is taken. This is
>   consistent with the requirement to have a final `default` clause in a `switch` statement.

MISRA C:2004 Rule 14.9 can be read as "Always use braces with `if` statements," which is still good advice today.

Comment: Seeing the braindead code which I tried to construct following the stated rules, just to learn there are more MISRA nonsense rules invalidating my attempts, I guess this is definitely the best solution (+1).

Comment: MISRA C:2004 is *very old.*  I would imagine that the newer standard applies many lessons learned.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity!
The company code standard, incorporating MISRA, hasn't been changed since long before 2012.